# Subplot positioning

Tags: r, ggplot2, subplot

I have a csv file with x, y data and x,y location columns.  i.e.

```
Test,Xloc,Yloc,X,Y
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,2,2
1,1,1,3,3
1,1,1,4,4
2,4,4,1,1
2,4,4,2,2
2,4,4,3,3
2,4,4,4,4
```

Assuming the subplot is 4x4 how could I put a line plot at the 1,1 location for test 1, and the 4,4 location for test 2?

I have ggplot2, and ggsubplot packages installed.  Seems maybe it's facet_grid, but not sure and not finding o good examples.  Basically there is going to be areas on the figure where there is no subplot.

Comment: So this is the data you want to plot? How do you plan to use subplot with this? Can you give some idea what the output will be?

Comment: Not the data I want to plot, but you have to start small.  The file I am using has over 1 million lines.  I am going to pull the X,Y values from specific tests given a criteria and then plot those all onto one figure depending on their XY locations contained in the csv file.  I can read the file and get all the data I want no problem.  The best pic I have found that is somewhat similar is here http://revolution-computing.typepad.com/.a/6a010534b1db25970b0177448319ad970d-pi Mine would be line plots not bar plots.  In python I used subplot2grid to accomplish this.

Comment: Even in that picture though not really what I will do.  I want each plot to have it's own X and Y axis values to show for each sub plot.

Comment: It's best to edit your original question rather than adding info in comments. It can be more neatly organized that way. I must admit i'm still having a hard time understanding this because it's abstract. See the guide on [how to create reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for ideas about building sample data sets to illustrate your point. Please don't post 1 million lines, just enough to get the idea of what you want.

Comment: This python plot is closer to what I want to do http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide-5.png but what I am plotting is tested over a circular pattern, so the sub plots would be laid out in a circular fasion.  Basically trying to see if issues exist on certain areas of the surface tested.

Comment: OK, I'll start adding to the original question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you are trying to achieve?

```
temp <- read.csv(text = "
Test,Xloc,Yloc,X,Y
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,2,2
1,1,1,3,3
1,1,1,4,4
2,4,4,1,1
2,4,4,2,2
2,4,4,3,3
2,4,4,4,4")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(temp, aes(X, Y)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ Test, scales = "free")
```

[image]